# Microsoft Word 2013 pictureframe for all pictures in document

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I have a large Microsoft Word 2013 document (on my Windows 10 Laptop) with much Text and many Pictures. I want all my **pictures to be in the center of an other pictures**. The other picture is **like a frame**. And **I want to be able to change all those "Pictureframes" at once** if I need to.

I don't need al them to automatically get the frame, but I want the frame to change if I say like: "Aww, I don't like this frame anymore, I want another one for all the pictures"

**How do I do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just completed the **PIC PAF** method:

**PIC PAF** means: **P**icture **I**n **C**hanging **P**icture **A**s **F**rame

An thats how the method works:

> 1. Go to Insert -> Pictures and choose your Picture
> 2. Instead of choosing "insert" you choose "link to file"
> 3. Then you insert the picture that will be inside the frame.
> 4. Change the layout of the inside picture to "in front of text"
> 5. Now you can just drag and drop the picture inside the frame and there you have it!